# Google Analytics PDF Download Tracking

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I found this script that tracks more than just PDF downloads.  I updated it to work with analytics.js the latest version of Google Analytics (GA).  But, the events aren't being recorded in GA.  I stepped through the code and put console.log at each ga('send'...)  I know it's getting to the correct line of code, but the ga('send') isn't being recorded in GA.  Any ideas?

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var filetypes = /\.(zip|exe|pdf|doc*|xls*|ppt*|mp3)$/i;
        var baseHref = '';
        if (jQuery('base').attr('href') != undefined)
            baseHref = jQuery('base').attr('href');
        jQuery('a').each(function() {
            var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            if (href && (href.match(/^https?\:/i)) && (!href.match(document.domain))) {
                jQuery(this).click(function() {
                    var extLink = href.replace(/^https?\:\/\//i, '');
                    ga('send','event','External Link','click',extLink);
                    if (jQuery(this).attr('target') != undefined && jQuery(this).attr('target').toLowerCase() != '_blank') {
                        setTimeout(function() { location.href = href; }, 200);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (href && href.match(/^mailto\:/i)) {
                jQuery(this).click(function() {
                    var mailLink = href.replace(/^mailto\:/i, '');
                    ga('send','event','Email Link','click',mailLink);
                });
            }
            else if (href && href.match(filetypes)) {
                jQuery(this).click(function() {
                    var extension = (/[.]/.exec(href)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(href) : undefined;
                    var filePath = href;
                    ga('send','event','Download Link','click-' + extension,filePath);
                    if (jQuery(this).attr('target') != undefined && jQuery(this).attr('target').toLowerCase() != '_blank') {
                        setTimeout(function() { location.href = baseHref + href; }, 200);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Check the network tab of the Dev console to see if you see the "collect" hit being sent, or enable GA Debugger to see if you can see the hits, or even (although not as reliable) check your RealTime reports. Data in GA doesn't update right away and may take up to 24 hours to process.

Comment: Thanks @nyuen.  The "collect" did get called.  I tried RealTime already, I don't see them there.  It's been 48 hrs since I started testing.  Yet I have no recorded events in GA.

Comment: Figured it out...I was looking at a filtered view in GA, that was excluding my traffic/events.